# How to declare an interface with an array of objects in Angular (typescript)?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I created an Angular project where I'm receiving an object with the following structure from the backend:

```
{
    status: "ok",
    totalResults: 12,
    articles: [
        {
            source: {
                id: null,
                name: "Sports Illustrated"
            },
            author: "Albert Breer",
            title: "Some Title",
            description: "Some description",
            urlToImage: "http://google.ch/someImage.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

I then tried to create an interface which corresponds to this object. Yet I struggled to define properties that refer to an object resp. an array of objects (e.g. `article`).

In my first attempt I tried to define my object inline:

```
export interface Noticias {
    status: string;
    totalResults: number;

    articles: Array<{
        id: string;
        name: string;
        title: string;
        description: string;
        urlToImage: string;
    }>
}
```

Then I tried to define the properties as duplicates:

```
export interface Noticias {
    status: string;
    totalResults: number;

    id: string;
    name: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    urlToImage: string;

    articles: Array<{
        id: string;
        name: string;
        title: string;
        description: string;
        urlToImage: string;
    }>
}
```

Visual Studio Code keeps showing me errors, therefore I doubt whether my approach is correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the json-structure on your first screenshot you'd rather create three separate interfaces: One for `Noticias`, one for `Article` and one for `Source`. Then `Noticias` contains an array of type `Article` and `Article` contains an object of type `Source`;

**noticias.model.ts:**

```
import { Article } from './article.model';

export interface Noticias {
  status: string;
  totalResults: number;

  articles: Article[];
}
```

**article.model.ts:**

```
import { Source } from './source.model';

export interface Article {
  source: Source;
  author: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  urlToImage: string;
}
```

**source.model.ts:**

```
export interface Source {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```